# How can Block direct access to drupal 6 site

Tags: drupal-6

i have developed a site on drupal 6 and now i want to Block direct access to any node url on my site,how can i Block any user to acces the site and redirect on login page from where they can create a new account if he doesnot have user id and passsword,so any one please help me regarding this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not allow any anonymous users to access content on your site, turn off the permission on the Permissions settings under User Management.

You could then set the default front page to /user so everyone who goes to the site would be greeted with the login screen (and be allowed to register a user, if needed).